# Is it true that in a superconductor the current will always flow without a any electric source?

Tags: electric-circuits, superconductivity

It came to my mind that when a superconductor is taken and a wire is joined to it to make it a complete circuit, the current is flowing through it. Now, I am removing the battery and joining the two ends of the superconductor together without the battery. Will the current flow through it after I remove the battery? As we know, a superconductor has zero resistance.

[image: Image showing the superconductor with and without battery in two cases.]

Comment: Please stop shouting.

Comment: In other words, does current obey Newton's first law?

Comment: YES THE CURRENT KEEPS FLOWING. THAT'S HOW SUPERCONDUCTING MAGNETS WORK. And turn off your caps lock, please.

Comment: Actually, in a perfect superconductor, it you connect it to  an emf source, will radiate tremndous amount of radiation and the current will eventually stop flowing. Superconductors have very high self inductance.

Comment: Is there any specific answer that why the current will flow  without any electrical source in a super conductor forever ?

Comment: An alternative point of view is that that the coil is charged with electrons and this electrons are aligned by their magnetic dipole moments. This is a self-holding process as long as the thermic chaotic movement does not destroy this alignments. This is why one need the deep cooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a superconductor, the electric resistance is equal to zero. This is why an electric current can circulate forever in a superconducting ring even when the battery has been unplugged! This is how magnetic fields are created in [MRIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging).

Source:-  http://www.supraconductivite.fr/en/index.php?p=supra-resistance-supra

Comment: Is there any specific answer that why the current will flow  without any electrical source in a super conductor forever ?

Comment: Current won't flow without any source. Once the source is disconnected from the superconductor the current flowing in that would continue.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) Take the [tour] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 3) If you have a good question, ask it! Just remember if you do so and get a satisfactory answer to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.